# Best Practices to handle multiple open workbooks in an Excel VSTO add-in

Tags: vb.net, vsto, add-in, excel

I'm working on an Excel VSTO add-in in VB.Net.  I am trying to address the question of knowing which workbook my add-in should be effecting given that a user may open or close many workbooks before, after, or during use of my main form.

The main functions all center around editing a main template file, which the user presumably the saves with useful names, and might come back to for reference or further editing.  The add-in opens a form and performs various functions like adding information from a database to a worksheet, or adding sheets to a workbook (and lots of stats).  Much of what I'm doing relies on calling a particular workbook:

```
        CurrentRun = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
        CurrentBook = CurrentRun.Workbooks(CurrentIndex)
```

Where `CurrentIndex` is the index from a combobox which is populated/updated with names of the currently open workbooks:

```
    ...
    ControlCurrentWBComboBox.Items.Clear()
    CurrentRun = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
    For n = 1 To CurrentRun.Workbooks.Count()
        ControlCurrentWBComboBox.Items.Add(CurrentRun.Workbooks(n).Name)
    Next
    CurrentRun = Nothing
    ...
```

This requires the user to select the workbook (by name) that they want to be working with.  This seemed like a good idea until I put it in front of 8 different users today.  Most eventually got used to having select the workbook, but not without a lot of grumbling and throwing errors (which were well handled).  2 users never got it, and were continually accidentally editing the wrong workbook, and throwing errors an hour into use.

Is there a better way to handle this?  I'm thinking of trying to make two versions: one with the above and one for people who need fewer options.  Is there a way to force a sort of 1-to-1 relationship you can get by putting VBA code in the workbook itself?

Am I way of base by even trying to deal with this or referencing anything other than ActiveWorkbook?

[Note: I'm a little scared by the blue warning that's telling me this is a subjective question.  I'm not meaning for it to be; perhaps I need help with the wording?]

Comment: I am slightly confused. If the 2 users who didn't select the relevant file from the combo then how did this line `CurrentBook = CurrentRun.Workbooks(CurrentIndex)` work? ideally `CurrentIndex` should not have any value... Or is it that it was pre-populated? If this was pre-populated then one solution that I can see to your problem is setting the combo to blank and then trapping that in case the user doesn't select the relevant workbook?

Comment: @SiddharthRout  It didn't work because it was null.  It threw an index error, which was handled by a message box " You need to choose a workbook to work with."  The two users never got used to this and thus threw the error constantly.  They also opened and closed lots of workbooks so the index changed frequently (thus requiring frequent updates of the selected workbook).  I thought this was an elegant solution till I watched that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Add-In does not "just work" with any open workbook, then you probably should not be using an Application Add-In; rather, you should be using a [Document Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcfbd2sk.aspx).

In this scenario, if the user has 3 workbooks open (that each have the Add-In), they will each operate in their own domain -- as If the others don't exist.

If this is an option in your environment, I would strongly recommend it as a Best Practice.

Comment: I considered this, and I still am.  At the moment the add-in deals with 6 different main templates and about 40 minor ones (and can detect which one it is working on/unrecognized books).  The problem was editing the unintended file and seemingly not being able to train some users. Perhaps I should build it into each of the main templates.

Comment: I decided that you're right, if it's not designed for "ALL" workbooks (even if it is designed for "Many" workbooks) then it should be dropped to a document level customization.  Any good resources for going from an App Add-in to a Document Customization?  I found plenty the other way.

Comment: I've never done it. If it were me I wouldn't try to modify your current project, I'd start a new Document-level Add-In project and copy code manually from the old one.  Good luck.